# How do I run/include/require remote javascript safely?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have an API for my bakery.  I want to receive my baking instructions from a remote URL (ex: a gist)

```
class Bakery{
    static bake(instructionsURL){
        const workers = ['bob','betty'];
        //const followInstructions = getFromURL(instructionsURL); //need help here
        const product = followInstructions(workers);
        console.log(product);
    }
}
```

I'd like to make sure the instructions are contained so that I don't risk the rest of my code.  I would like to do something like a module require or import.  I can't find a solution where I don't have to blindly execute unknown code...

Comment: You shouldn't need to execute any code to get baking instructions.

Comment: Getting a remote script and executing it safely are two different issues. The first part is relatively easy [using native node or a library](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html). The second part is harder. Why do you want to do this in the first place? What's the use-case?

Comment: updated the code to better show use case

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the code in a sandboxed iframe on an external domain, exactly like [what StackOverflow does](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to handle running untrusted code in its snippets feature.

Do note that very old browsers (think before IE11) do not support sandboxed iframes.